# LineLegend behaves differently in ListPlot in Mathematica Version10.0 or later

Tags: plotting, legending

Suppose I want a line legend for a list plot:

```
dat = RandomReal[{.8, 1.2}, 40]*Range@40;

ListPlot[Transpose@{Range@40, dat}, 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{Style["I want a line legend!!!", 
  18]}], {.4, .8}]]
```

However, the output doesn't show a line legend but something that looks like a point legend:

[image]

I use Mathematica 10.0.2 on Windows 7.  Is this a bug?

Comment: *Mma 10* -- there are a few sub-versions, please, add the necessary version info.

Comment: To check version, use Help -> About in the GUI or use both `$Version` and `$ReleaseNumber`.  Unfortunately `$Version` and `$VersionNumber` will not contain the *z* part of an *x.y.z* form version number.

Comment: @Szabolcs how did you know that my $ReleaseNumber gives 2? By GUI->About It's 10.0.2 indeed!

Comment: @Harry I have 10.0.2 installed and the date of December 4, 2014 (in `$Version`) matches with yours.  If yours showed an earlier date, I couldn't tell if it was 10.0.0 or 10.0.1 as I don't have those versions any more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<del>This is not a bug.</del>  I *think* that this is not a bug, see addendum.

Based on my (limited!) experience, I believe that `LineLegend` and `PointLegend` are in fact the very same thing with differing default options.  `LineLegend` has `Joined -> True` while `PointLegend` has `Joined -> False` by default, but otherwise they are identical.

The syntax you used, i.e. `LineLegend[{"label1", "label2", ...}]` causes the legend to inherit the style from the plot, which means `Joined -> False`.  You can fix this by specifying the option manually.

```
LineLegend[{Style["I want a line legend!!!", 18]}, Joined -> True]
```

If you use `PointLegend` instead, it will do the same thing.  The only important factor is the values of the `Joined` option.

If you use these legends outside of the `PlotLegends` option of some type of plot, they will not inherit any options and will behave as their name would suggest (and as determined by their default options).

---

#### Addendum

Harry points out that in version 9 these legends do not inherit the `Joined` option from the parent plot, thus `LineLegend` always gives a line and `PointLegend` always gives a point.

Should we consider this behaviour change a breakage in v10?  I don't think so because the v9 behaviour also causes problems.  In v9, `ListPlot[Transpose@{Range@40, dat}, PlotLegends -> {"label"}, Joined -> True]` uses a point legend, even though the plot has a line.  This seems to have been fixed in v10 by causing the legend to inherit the `Joined` option from the parent.

Comment: seems it's a new feature of version10(version 9 behaves differently). It's quite reasonable after all.

Comment: @Harry You're right, see update.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version
```

> "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

```
dat = Transpose@{Range@40, RandomReal[{.8, 1.2}, 40]*Range@40};

Legended[
 ListPlot[dat],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{Blue},
   {Style["I want a line legend!!!", 14]}],
  {.3, .8}]]
```

[image]